# How to use ReadWriteLock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have a bufferPool which stores a lot of objects. In order to prevent different threads writing the same object and at the same for efficiency I use `ReadWriteLock`. But I am not too sure about how it works. After I find the object I want to access,

```
if(perm.equals(Permissions.READ_ONLY)) {                    
  readLock.lock();
} else if(Permissions.READ_WRITE) {                 
  writeLock.lock(); 
}
return the object I want to access
```

How does the system know which object the program is trying to access and lock it? 
Or my syntax here is wrong? Help!!! Thanks

Comment: Your idea of a buffer pool is somewhat different to mine.  I construct buffer pools by pushing buffer class instances onto an ArrayBlockingQueue. Once a thread pops an object, no other thread can write to it because no other thread can get at it.  I've never seen any need for multi-level locks - either a thread has complete read/write access to a buffer instance or it has no access at all.

Comment: Exactly. The pool is for *free* buffers. There are only two actions: put something into it or take something out of it. Both are write actions. You don't need anything beyond synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't know what you're trying to lock.  If you want to use lock objects for a series of items, you'll have to have a lock for each item, or use one lock for the entire object set (which could be a big bottleneck).  This is an example where a single lock is used to synchronize access.

```
// You'll need to create this somewhere else, in your constructor
// or some other routine that gets called once.
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(); 


// Then when you want to access:
lock.lock();
try {
 ... // do stuff with the data
}
finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I son't know of any WriteReadLock in java so I'll assume you're talking about ReadWriteLock, First ReadWriteLock is just an interface. You need to declare an implementation like ReentrantReadWriteLock somewhere. It is this instance that maintains the non-exclusive read lock and the exclusive write lock.

The lock instance is what the runtime grabs a monitor on. Look at the implementation its just some fanciness over top of regular old `wait()`,`notify()`, and `notifyall()`. You call in to get the lock instance. you call `lock()` when you start and `unlock()` when your done.

Besides that it is best practice to use locks in try-catch-finally with the `unlock` in the finally to ensure that it will get unlocked no matter what.

Comment: Actually I don't want to release the lock right away. I need to carry the lock a long time and then release the lock. what should I do? and seems like I can still write the object even there is a read lock to that?

Comment: Nope, the write lock blocks everyone. No one gets a lock till the writer is done.

Comment: If you don't care if people read volatile data then just have a non-synchronized read only method and only share a lock among writing threads in a different method. Or save your self the trouble and get rid of the lock all together and have a synchronized write method and an unsynchronized read method.